# How to make a animated sidein navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make the following slidein navigation bar? Is it possible without using any plugins and just stick with CSS3?

http://middle-earth.thehobbit.com/map

Comment: Yes, something very close can be done with CSS. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can't make it slide in and out via a click on a button, but you could handle all of the animation with CSS. you'll probably need to use both CSS and JS

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No plugins, very simple markup, css transitions, and a few lines of javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/7A5T6/6/

```
#menu{
height:100%;
transition:1s;
width:200px;
margin-left:-200px;
}

button{
position:absolute;
right:-30px;    
}
```

Javascript:

```
var open = document.getElementById('open')
var menu = document.getElementById('menu')

open.addEventListener('click',openit,false);

var i = 0;

function openit(){
    if(i==0){
        menu.style.marginLeft= "0px"
        i=1
    }
    else{
        menu.style.marginLeft= "-200px"
        i=0
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but.. how do you stick text in it to move with the flyout.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7A5T6/6/

Changed it to have a fixed width and it moves with the margins instead. Updating answer now.

Comment: @Rolando does this work for you now? I made a sexy implementation based on this that you can use if you like (please change up the style a bit if you care)... http://allthetime.co.nf/x.html